# How do I send email on from a Google G Suite Group on another domain?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to send emails from a G Suite Google Group address e.g. `group@mydomain.com`. The account I will be using to send emails is in another G Suite domain, e.g. `user@anotherdomain.com`. I can verify the access with a confirmation code, but I am required to provide an SMTP account as well. I provide an SMTP username/password on the same G Suite Domain as the group, e.g. `smtpuser@mydomain.com`:

[image]

Now whenever I send an email from group@mydomain.com, the emails always show up as originating from the email I provided for the SMTP username, `smtpuser@mydomain.com` rather than the group address of `group@mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've struggled with this configuration forever and finally got an answer! You have to make sure the user information provided for the SMTP configuration is **also configured to send email on behalf of the grou**p.

So in the example I posted, you need to configure `smtpuser@mydomain.com` to send email from `group@mydomain.com` as well as configuring `user@anotherdomain.com` to send email from `group@mydomain.com`.

I sure hope this helps save someone time!!

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to do same setup, with `user@anotherdomain.com` being a plain GMail account. I've followed your steps and additionally also enabled "Less Secure Apps" mode in my `smtpuser@mydomain.com` GSuite account. Now I'm stuck on the following error when trying to register SMTP details:

Oops, we weren't able to finish. Please verify that you have entered the exact settings provided by your other email service. Contact your other email administrator for further details.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this @Tom Rossi and @Neil! I was able to get beyond the verification step using the steps above and after enabling "Less Secure Apps" mode.

However, I've tried to send email from this group a handful of times and after clicking "Send". it seems to pause and never complete. Anyone else run into anything similar?

Comment: Also, what is the expected behavior for people in the group when you send an email _as_ someone in a group? Will they just get the replies? Any recommendations on how to ensure all members of the group see each and every message sent?

Comment: > However, I've tried to send email from this group a handful of times and after clicking "Send". it seems to pause and never complete. Anyone else run into anything similar?



I finally got past this part by just doing a hard refresh of Gmail itself.